# Command to replace specific column of csv file for first 100 rows

Tags: awk

Following command is replacing second column with value e in a complete csv file, 
but what if i want to replace only in first 100 rows.

```
awk -F, '{$2="e";}1' OFS=, file
```

Rest of the rows of csv file should be intact..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`awk -F, 'NR<101{$2="e";}1' OFS=, file`

`NR` built-in variable gives you either the total number of records being processed or line number depending on the usage. In the above awk example, `NR` variable has line number. When you put the pattern `NR<101` the action will become true for first 100 lines. Once it is false, it will default to `1` which will print remaining lines as-is.

Comment: @Jaypal..what if i have to apply above condition for 100-200 rows of csv file

Comment: @user752590 Put pattern as `awk -F, 'NR>99 && NR<201{$2="e";}1' OFS=, file`

Comment: How can I specify that I want to append e to only some rows and only some columns? For example I want to add e to columns greater than 10 in row 1?

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
awk -F, 'NR<=100{$2="e"}1' OFS=, file
```

Comment: Or even FNR could be used if multiple files are given as argument. But the result will be one big stream.

Comment: How can I specify that I want to append e to only some rows and only some columns? For example I want to add e to  columns greater than 10 in row 1.